# PHP - mysql dump doesn't work with symbol in password

Tags: php, mysql

I tried the `mysqldump` in php

```
shell_exec("mysqldump --user=$username --password=$password --host=$host $database > dump.sql");
```

Works fine if password is plain. But when there's a symbol in the password `&` in my case, it does't work. Any idea why, or how this can be resolved?

Short answer could be don't put symbols in your password. But that's not the answer I'm looking for and some DB passwords are beyond my reach. So I need a solution or a workaround.

Comment: did you try to put quotes around password? just in case

Comment: have you tried using the escapeshellcmd function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: using quotes worked. thanks.

Comment: Yep, and using quotes will work until there is a quote in your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using quotes worked. Thanks +Mubin

```
 shell_exec("mysqldump --user='$username' --password='$password' --host=$host $databaseName > dump.sql");
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using some unknown input, I'd use [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/manual/function.escapeshellcmd.php), which should be able to deal with everything (including having a `'` in your password).